# tomcat6 not run solr4.9 on centos : Application at context path /solr could not be started

Tags: solr, centos, tomcat6, solr4

I was following [this instructions](http://andres.jaimes.net/878/setup-lucene-solr-centos-tomcat/), but it didn't work.

I use tomcat6 and Solr4.9 on CentOS.

Tomcat run perfect, but when I press start the Solr in Tomcat Web Application Manager, this message appear:

> FAIL - Application at context path `/solr` could not be started

In `/solr` I've

In my `web.xml` I have :

```
<env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-value>/home/solr</env-entry-value>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

This is in the error log:

> Jun 26, 2014 4:34:30 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009 Jun 26, 2014 4:34:30 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/25 config=null Jun 26, 2014 4:34:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in 1045 ms Jun 26, 2014 4:34:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start SEVERE: Error filterStart Jun 26, 2014 4:34:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start SEVERE: Context [/solr] startup failed due to previous errors root@server.smarttags-lab.com [conf]#

Comment: And what is there on `/solr`? Is the context path set correctly? What is the configuration. We need more info.

Comment: ok this is web.xml
"
 <env-entry>
       <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
       <env-entry-value>/home/solr</env-entry-value>
       <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    </env-entry>
"

i just change this file

Comment: this is the error log
"
Jun 26, 2014 4:34:30 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Jun 26, 2014 4:34:30 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/25  config=null
Jun 26, 2014 4:34:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1045 ms
Jun 26, 2014 4:34:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Jun 26, 2014 4:34:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/solr] startup failed due to previous errors
root@server.smarttags-lab.com [conf]#

Comment: Hi!, did you remove the comment markers in web.xml?

Comment: yes
know i work on ubuntu localy
after that i will go back to centos

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Solr Exception: Could not find necessary SLF4j logging jars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415948/how-to-fix-solr-exception-could-not-find-necessary-slf4j-logging-jars)

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> Application at context path /solr could not be started.

is very general, so you should look for more specific error further up in your `localhost` log.

The most common issue is misconfiguration of Solr (assuming all the files are in the right place) by not placing necessary SLF4j logging jars into Java class folder therefore Apache Solr failed to initialize.

If that's the case, you need to copy the `SLF4j` logging jars from `<solr>/example/lib/ext/*.jar` into Tomcat Lib (e.g. `TOMCAT_HOME/lib`, `/usr/share/tomcat/lib`) or Webapp Lib directory (e.g. `TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/lib`). These jars will set up `SLF4J` and `log4j`. If you're using Jetty, these SLF4j logging jars need to go in the jetty `lib/ext` directory. For other containers, the corresponding directory should be used, so check [SolrLogging](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging) page for further information.

See: [How to fix Solr Exception: Could not find necessary SLF4j logging jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16415948/55075) for more details.